# Rails Active Admin custom queries for resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a resource and I want to show information from another related table in the index view. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. The answer is:

```
 column "Account ID" do |refund|
  Account.find_by_character_name(refund.character_name).id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also query it with the relation

`column ("Car Model") { |user| user.car.attribute_name if user.car }`